# How to get latest code from Visual Studio Online using alternate credentials?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-process, azure-devops

As part of our continuous integration process, we want to get the latest code from Visual Studio Online in order to execute automated tests locally.

We can already download the latest builds, but we cannot execute Coded UI tests correctly with the compiled assemblies, for some reason. Thus, we want to get the latest code in order to compile and execute it locally. How could I get the latest code from Visual Studio Online from a TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) project?

Comment: You should probably also try to find out why Coded UI tests with compiled assemblies doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, we already found why our Coded UI tests were not working, althought TFService compiles correctly our project, a dll that is genereated in TFService is old for our purposes, specifically Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework.dll, this one is compiled in TFService with 11.0.60.222.0 and we need 11.0.60223.1, so we added an script that replaces locally with newer version and our ATCs works as expected, maybe is because we use Visual Studio Update 2 CTP4, I'm not sure, anyways it will be interesting to know how to accomplish the original question......